# jquery Link click in Datatables not working

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm using the jquery datatables plugin and I have two links in the first row.  Those links are used to send a ajax on click.  Since I implemented datatables (I had just a table beforehand) it stopped working.  I've looked around and tried two things:

I originally had

```
               $(".approveReject").click(function () {
                   OnApproveRejectClick("voavi", this);
               });
```

But replaced that with

```
$(document).delegate("click", '.approveReject', function (event) {
alert("clicked");
});
```

with no success, so I tried to add the fnInitComplete callback to the datatable init object:

```
        "fnInitComplete": function () {
            $(".approveReject").click(function () {
                OnApproveRejectClick("voavi", this);
            });
        }
```

still nothing.  The click doesn't work at all.  Any idea what I need to do in order to bind the click event to my links?  Thanks

Full datatable init

```
    $("#voaviTable").dataTable({
        "bJQueryUI": true,
        "bScrollInfinite": true,
        "bScrollCollapse": true,
        "iDisplayLength": 30,
        "sScrollY": "450px",
        "oLanguage": {
            "sSearch": "Filter: "
        },
        "aaSorting": [],
        "fnInitComplete": function () {
            $(".approveReject").click(function () {
                OnApproveRejectClick("voavi", this);
            });
        }
    });
```

table example row:

```
<tr class="even">
<td class=" ">
<a id="lnkApprove" class="approveReject" href="#">Approve</a>
|
<a id="lnkReject" class="approveReject" href="#">Reject</a>
<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-check" style="display: none;"></span>
<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-close" style="display: none;"></span>
<img id="loaderGif" height="16px" style="display: none;" src="../../Content/images/loader.gif">
</td>
<td class="statusID "> 32 </td>
<td class="statusText "> new </td>
<td class=" "> </td>
<td class=" "> </td>
<td class=" "> Cote de Blancs </td>
<td class=" "> </td>
<td class=" "> </td>
<td class=" ">
<td class=" "> 10/5/2012 2:54:05 PM </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Check when this is fired..  "fnInitComplete"

Comment: Looks like the handler is being bound multiple times to the same event

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using delegate wrong

```
$(document).delegate( '.approveReject', "click",function (event) {// <-- notice where the selector and event is
    alert("clicked");
});
```

Though if you are using jQuery 1.7+ use .on()

```
$(document).on("click", '.approveReject', function (event) {
    alert("clicked");
});
```

best thing would to bind the event to your table though as it's the closest static parent element (I'm guessing)

```
$('#voaviTable').on('click','.approveReject', function (event) {
```

> $(document).delegate(selector, events, data, handler);  // jQuery 1.4.3+
>
> $(document).on(events, selector, data, handler);        // jQuery 1.7+

Comment: Thanks man!  I know I should be using on, but I don't have time the change jquery and test everything.  Your solution worked!  Thanks